# Popovers don't work correctly on table rows using table-striped style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, popover

After upgrading to bootstrap 3 generating a popover on table rows has an unexpected hovering effect on the table row. Popovers don't behave correctly on table rows using table-striped style. Removal of the table-striped style is one fix but you lose that effect. Only tested in Chrome. The last working version was 2.1.1.

Bootstrap 2.2.2: http://jsfiddle.net/tomshaw/9N4fs/

Is there a way to give the popover a container to stop this effect? Or some similar technique?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Module</th>
      <th>Controller</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Recorded</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="popover" data-content="Content One" title="System Information">
      <td>Utilities</td>
      <td>Transaction</td>
      <td>Export</td>
      <td>2012-12-26 11:58:10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="popover" data-content="Content Two" title="System Information">
      <td>Utilities</td>
      <td>Reports</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>2012-12-26 12:47:30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="popover" data-content="Content Three" title="System Information">
      <td>Utilities</td>
      <td>User</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>2012-12-26 12:48:27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


// Weird table row table-striped hover effect. Broken in bootstrap 
// 2.2.2 working in 2.1.1 Using selector option has same effect.

$('body').popover({placement:"top",trigger:"hover",selector:'tr[id=popover]'});


table {
    margin:50px 5px 0 5px;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what behavior you are going for. When I removed the table-striped the behavior of the pop-up was the exact same. Also you are using mutliple ID tags with the same name in your `tr` s. I updated your example to fix a few of these things and I rearranged the popup to an area where I assumed that you wanted it. Let me know if that helps and please remember not to use multiple id's with the same name.

Here is what I did to move the popover:

Added:

```
.popover{
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle make sure you look at the changes in the HTML and the JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/9N4fs/30/

Comment: Hi Thunda, thanks for your answer. I probably should have been a bit clearer- it's not the behaviour of the pop up itself, rather the behaviour of the striped table. When I hover over a row, only one row should highlight. When I add the popup, it dramatically changes the highlighting effect of the table.

Comment: I have been looking at how to move popovers to the left though - thanks for answering a question I hadn't even posted yet.